# How can a HID device control the description shown for it in Windows Device Manager?

Tags: windows, usb, hid

I am writing the firmware for a USB HID device. When it is connected to a Windows PC (running Windows 8.1, if that makes any difference) it gets listed in Device Manager, under "Human Interface Devices", as "HID-compliant vendor-defined device". For obvious reasons it would be preferable for a nicer description to be shown.

I'd have guessed that the description would be taken from the USB string descriptor table, perhaps from the entry specified in the device descriptor as containing the product name. This doesn't appear to happen. Perhaps there is an error in my descriptors, but when I connect a USB analyser during enumeration it correctly identifies the manufacturer name, product name, and serial number string.

A little googling suggests that the Device Manager's descriptions can be controlled from a driver's `.inf` file, but this device doesn't have its own drivers.

Am I out of luck, or is there a way for an HID device to determine how it is described by the Device Manager? If there is, what is it?

(Related prior SO question: [Rename a USB HID device under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767397/rename-a-usb-hid-device-under-windows). An answer to that question says that you need to write a Windows device driver to do this, but comments on the answer indicate that this shouldn't apply to HID devices, and the answerer concedes this. Unfortunately no further suggestions are to be found there. That question may actually be trying to ask essentially the same thing as I am, but if so it's ill-titled; I am not trying to *rename* anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Windows have default drivers for HID input devices.
This is the main advantage of this [USB class of devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/supported-usb-classes).

Windows installs driver for a USB device first, and then driver for each of its [USB interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbspec/ns-usbspec-_usb_interface_descriptor) and creates child devices node under USB device. Each interface may be a [HID device](https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes) interface (`0x03` in `USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR.bInterfaceClass`) and in this case Windows parses HID device descriptor and creates child device node for each its [top-level collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/top-level-collections):

[image]

But unfortunately this HID [Top-Level Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/top-level-collections) driver just do set the [DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-friendlyname) for the device in accordance to its type and it will be something like "HID-compliant mouse" as this means that the driver for a Mouse Usage type (Usage Page 0x0001, Usage 0x0001) is installed (see [HID Spec](https://www.usb.org/document-library/device-class-definition-hid-111) for more info).

Good news here that HID-aware application can use [HidD_GetManufacturerString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getmanufacturerstring)/[HidD_GetProductString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getproductstring)/[HidD_GetSerialNumberString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getserialnumberstring) functions to get device string information from the corresponding [USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbspec/ns-usbspec-_usb_interface_descriptor) (or [USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbspec/ns-usbspec-_usb_device_descriptor) if `USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR.iInterface` is zero). Note also that these string may be empty (not set by manufacturer).

If you really want to set [DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/devpkey-device-friendlyname) for your HID device in device tree then you have to create a special driver `*.inf` file for it. You need to use this hardware ID:

[image]

You can look at example inf file that changes device name in `C:\Windows\INF\msmouse.inf`.